# Accidentally modified MBR; can't boot to Linux anymore

Tags: linux, mbr

I'm a dual boot user running Windows 10 and Kali linux. I rebuild the MBR by mistake using partition wizard. Now I lost access to my linux

- I lost swap area menu but I still have the partition
- I tried to use easy BCD but it didn t work

Comment: what partitioning scheme is your hard disk employing MBR or GPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot linux live
- chroot in root
- repair grub